# Compilation error when trying to add "?" operator

Tags: html, angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

The following code snippet works fine.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="formulario.get('email')?.errors['required']">
    Please inform the email
</div>
```

However, when I try to add a ? to check if errors exist, I get a compilation error. The code below gives an error:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="formulario.get('email')?.errors?.['required']">
            Please inform the email
</div>
```

Output:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
> Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 34 in [formulario.get('email')?.errors?.['required']] in ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.html@12:55 (")" #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="formulation">

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
```

Comment: "errors?.['required']" or "errors?['required']" ?

Comment: Looks fine. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gqsm4q?file=src/app/app.component.html). Which Angular version and Typescript version you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downgrading to Angular 8, it is able to reproduce the issue mentioned. It is more likely that your current syntax is not compatible with the old Angular version.

As an alternative, work with the `&&` operator which works the same with the optional chaining (`?.`).

```
<div
  class="alert alert-danger"
  role="alert"
  *ngIf="
    formulario &&
    formulario.get('email') &&
    formulario.get('email').errors &&
    formulario.get('email').errors['required']
  "
>
  Please inform the email
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hazg8s?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email')

Comment: Hmmm, did you create instance for `formulario` by assigning `FormGroup` instance to it ? And your `formulario` contains `email` FormControl?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I did

Comment: Hmmm, updated my answer. More likely you need to validate whether each value is neither`null`, `undefined` before proceed for next validation.

Comment: Same error. Im not sure what to do

Comment: Can you create a demo in StackBlitz with your existing code to reproduce the issue? Thanks.